# Starting and Disposing JFrame inside Runnable object, howto

Tags: java, swing

What is the correct way of disposing a frame which is created inside a Runnable object?

The code below returns a null pointer exception when the endDialog is called before the LoadingRunnable has completed its constructor.
How can the endDialog be executed after the constructor has finished?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LoadingRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private JFrame jFrame;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        jFrame = new JFrame("Window");
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Loading...");
        jPanel.add(label);
        jFrame.setContentPane(jPanel);
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void endDialog()
    {
        jFrame.setVisible(false);
        jFrame.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        LoadingRunnable l = new LoadingRunnable();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(l);
        //work done here
        l.endDialog();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a concurrency problem here because [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) schedules your runnable class execution in the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) asynchronously while your `main` thread's flow still running, causing a NPE.

The correct way to dispose a frame is through events, just as Swing is designed to be used. For instance by clicking the "X" (close) button or by dispatching a [WindowEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html):

```
frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

You may want to take a look to this question too: [Optional way to close a dialog window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22105496/1795530)

#### In addition

If you just want to show something during your application start up, then you can use [SplashScreen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) API instead of `JFrame`. See [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) for further details.

[image]

Based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781402/execute-only-one-instance-of-swingworker) and this new one, I'd suggest you read the whole [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial to understand about common concurrency problems in Swing and how to deal with them.

Comment: It's exactly there the problem, I want the "loading..." frame to show in the EDT and the main thread to communicate to the frame when to hide. Is there some example?

Answer (score 0):

Ok found how:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Loading
{

    private JFrame jFrame;

    public void startDialog()
    {
        jFrame = new JFrame("Window");
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Loading...");
        jPanel.add(label);
        jFrame.setContentPane(jPanel);
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void endDialog()
    {
        jFrame.setVisible(false);
        jFrame.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        final Loading l = new Loading();
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    l.startDialog();
                }
            });
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    l.endDialog();
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What's with the loop? Maybe you should look into a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Ah ok no, the loop is just to show that endDialog() is never called before startDialog() thus returning a null pointer as in previous version.